# Remove whitespace in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lot of records in my database with excessive spaces:

```
to buy  books is  like to buy
bad   journalists  aren't taken   hostage
  for your   information  this isn't    what we do
```

Is there a way to, in (My)SQL
 - replace all spaces by just one
 - strip all whitespace from the beginning and end of the string?

Otherwise I could always do it in php, looking all records through

```
$cleaned = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

But that would require much more time I imagine (I have millions of records)

Comment: You can use Regular expressions in the database level, too.

Comment: @ypercube that true but [replace is a pain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161395/mysql-regex-replace).

Comment: I asked a very similar question a few days ago [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193297/best-way-to-clean-mysql-string-data-to-plaintext-and-trim-beginning-end-spaces](here) Might get you started.

Comment: @Conrad: yeah and I just noticed the millions rows mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a one time operation you could just export the records to some textformat (csv, sql inserts..) and to the replacement with a good texteditor that support regular expressions.
Gives you a backup when your regexpr wasn't that perfect after all. Import in to a new table afterwards.

When you take the replace in code way you could filter out the records who don't need the replacement with something like "where field like "%  %"" to speed things up.

Last but not least you will have to update your servercode that writes these records to filter out the extra spaces **before** writing to the db.

Answer (score 0):

There's only built-in support for pattern matching using regex in MySQL. It is possible to use a user defined function such as http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/ to solve your need.

This one does not support multibyte characters. So, you're limited to single byte character encodings with this solution.